# Angular tsconfig cannot use different noImplicitAny settings for different projects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 15 workspace with a main app and multiple independent projects (aka libraries). For the main app and *some* projects, I want to set `noImplicitAny: true` for the TypeScript compiler, but for some others, I want it to remain false (the default). The `tsconfig.lib.json` files inside the libraries are extending the main `tsconfig.json` from the root Angular folder (although I tried removing the `extends` as well, no difference, read below).

The problem is, no matter what I do, I keep getting errors about `noImplicitAny` from the libraries where it is even explicitly set to false! It seems that the TypeScript compiler disregards the individual `tsconfig.lib.json` settings inside those libraries and takes the global setting.

Moreover, I tried moving the setting from the main `tsconfig.json` in the root folder, to the app-specific `src/tsconfig.app.json` and I *still get* the same error from the libraries!

These are the other contents of the main `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "module": "es2022",
        "target": "es2022",
        "lib": ["es2022", "dom"],
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

We are **not** using "full" TypeScript strict mode.

What am I missing?